# Is it possible to set external scope variables inside a service in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

I'm using an angular service, which I'm sharing between multiple controllers. Is there a way to set scope variables inside those services?

This is what I have so far:

```
angular.module( "names", [] )
    .factory( "_names", [ function()
    {
        return {

            initName: function (name, $scope) {
                $scope.$scope.name = name
            }
        }
    }])
;
```

And inside the actual controller that uses the service, I have:

```
angular.module("another.Place")
  .controller("NameCtrl", ["$scope", "_names", [function( $scope, _names) {

   $scope.name = "blank"
    _names.initName("Jane", $scope)
    console.log($scope.name)
 }])
;
```

So, that `$scope.name` inside the calling controller is now `Jane`, and the console log prints out `Jane`. Obviously, this isn't a very useful function, but just as an example. Is this possible, and how is it normally done?

Comment: Avoid passing $scope to service, it can cause more problem than solving it. Services are singleton and any property on the service an be access and updated by any controller.

Comment: Much simpler to think in terms of sharing objects that are stored in the service. Then controller scopes only have references to parent object and can easily change any property from any component and as such a change in controller1 will affect change in controller2 due to `inheritance`